# one sample t test for clustered data in R

Tags: t-test, cluster-sample

How shall I do one sample t test for clustered data? For instance, I have N = 100 number of observations, which are obtained from 5 different regions. I'd like to test whether the outcome y is significantly different from mu = 0.

Any R package recommend?

Thanks so much.